# SpecFlow and Testing with the Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, specflow

We just decided to use SpecFlow in for our unit testing and I created the first scenario.

The tests are running fine,except for one of them and it calls a function in my code.

So obviously that test caught a bug in that function.

I put a breakpoint on the first line of the function which the tests calls and Right Clicked on the Specs project and selected **Run With Debugger.**

The breakpoint in my function though never gets hit, only the breakpoints in the tests.

So my question is **"How do you make SpecFlow run with the Debugger so that I can truly debug my code"**

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Comment: I added a App.Config file with the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <generator allowDebugGeneratedFiles="false" allowRowTests="true" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>

but it does not help. 
I am using VS 2008

Comment: I figured out the issue. If by any chance the references to the projects that the code resides in are not picked from the Projects tab on the Add Reference Dialog but using the Browse option then it wasn't working. Re-added the references via the Projects tab and it's all good. Not sure if this was the case just with me ( maybe I was pointing to a bad reference) or in general

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for Visual Studio (version 2019 at the time of writing this answer):

1. Debug > Options > General
2. Disable "Enable Just My Code".

Answer (score 1):

I too have encountered this behaviour. What worked for me is placing a breakpoint in the scenario and also a breakpoint in the step definition file. When you then choose "Run with debugger" you will find that program execution will stop at both breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Resharper to run your tests you have to change the VS option:
Tools -> Options -> Specflow -> Test Runner from Auto to ReSharper

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Debugging-Tests

```
<generator allowDebugGeneratedFiles="true">
```